# What does error message -(AttributeError: Worm instance has no attribute 'vx') mean and how can i fix it?

Tags: python, pygame

I've been following [a tutorial](http://lorenzod8n.wordpress.com/category/pygame-tutorial/) but keep getting the following error
`AttributeError: Worm instance has no attribute 'move'`
I'm not sure exactly what it means or how to fix it. The error refers to line 44 towards the bottom the line is `w.move()`**(this one's solved look below)**

```
import pygame

class Worm:
    """A Worm."""
    def __init__(self, surface, x, y, length):
        self.surface = surface
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.length = length
        self.dir_x = 0
        self.dir_y = -1
        self.body = []
        self.crashed = False

    def key_event(self, event):
        """Handle Key events that affect the worm."""
        if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
            self.dir_x = 0
            self.dir_y = -1
        elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
            self.dir_x = 0
            self.dir_y = 1
        elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
            self.dir_x = -1
            self.dir_y = 0
        elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
            self.dir_x = 1
            self.dir_y = 0 
    def draw(self):
        for x, y in self.body:
            self.surface.set_at((x, y), (255, 255, 255))

width = 640
height = 400

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
running = True

w = Worm(screen, width/2, height/2, 200)

while running:
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    w.move()
    w.draw()

    if w.crashed or w.x <= 0 or w.x >= width -1 or w.y <= 0 or w.y >= height -1:
        print "crash"
        running = False

    for event in  pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            w.key_event(event)

    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(240)
```

----------Change --------

code:

```
import pygame

class Worm:
    """A Worm."""
    def __init__(self, surface, x, y, length):
        self.surface = surface
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.length = length
        self.dir_x = 0
        self.dir_y = -1
        self.body = []
        self.crashed = False

    def key_event(self, event):
        """Handle Key events that affect the worm."""
        if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
            self.dir_x = 0
            self.dir_y = -1
        elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
            self.dir_x = 0
            self.dir_y = 1
        elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
            self.dir_x = -1
            self.dir_y = 0
        elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
            self.dir_x = 1
            self.dir_y = 0 
    def draw(self):
        for x, y in self.body:
            self.surface.set_at((x, y), (255, 255, 255))
    def move(self):
        """move worm."""
        self.x += self.vx
        self.y += self.vy

        if (self.x, sel.y) in self.body:
            self.crashed = True

        self.body.insert(0, (self.x, self.y))

        if len(self.body) > self.length:
            self.body.pop()

    def draw(self):
        #for x, y self.body:
        #    self.surface.set_at((x, y),self.color)
        x, y = self.body[0]
        self.surface.set_at((x, y), self.color)
        x, y = self.body[-1]
        self.surface.set_at((x, y), (0, 0, 0))


width = 640
height = 400

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
running = True

w = Worm(screen, width/2, height/2, 200)

while running:
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    w.move()
    w.draw()

    if w.crashed or w.x <= 0 or w.x >= width -1 or w.y <= 0 or w.y >= height -1:
        print "crash"
        running = False

    for event in  pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            w.key_event(event)

    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(240)
```

and Error -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Enrique/Dropbox/Public/snakegametutorial.py", line 65, in <module>
    w.move()
  File "C:/Users/Enrique/Dropbox/Public/snakegametutorial.py", line 34, in move
    self.x += self.vx
AttributeError: Worm instance has no attribute 'vx'
```

Comment: `w.move()` Move doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AttributeError` indicates that you attempted to access a property or method on an object that was not defined in the object's class definition.

It just seems like you have not progressed far enough in the tutorial code to have defined the `Worm.move()` method.  It occurs at line 43 of the tutorial, just before `Worm.draw()`.  You are headed for another `AttributeError` on the `draw()` method, as you've not yet defined that one either. Just add both of these to the `Worm` class definition.

```
 43     def move(self):
 44         """ Move the worm. """
 45         self.x += self.vx
 46         self.y += self.vy
 47 
 48         if (self.x, self.y) in self.body:
 49             self.crashed = True
 50 
 51         self.body.insert(0, (self.x, self.y))
 52 
 53         if (self.grow_to > self.length):
 54             self.length += 1
 55 
 56         if len(self.body) > self.length:
 57             self.body.pop()
 58
 59     def draw(self):
 60         #for x, y in self.body:
 61         #    self.surface.set_at((x, y), self.color)
 62         x, y = self.body[0]
 63         self.surface.set_at((x, y), self.color)
 64         x, y = self.body[-1]
 65         self.surface.set_at((x, y), (0, 0, 0))
```

**Update**

You're now receiving the `AttributeError` on `Worm.vx`  because you're missing that property (also `vy`) from `Worm.__init__()`. Compare your code to the code under the heading **The improved game** on the tutorial page. When you encounter further errors, compare your class definition to the tutorial's.

Add to `__init__()`

```
def __init__(self, surface):
    ...
    ...
    self.vx = 0
    self.vy = -1
    ...
    ...
```

Comment: i tried it out  but i got new erors.I think i changed the program as you said... i posted the error and changes up top

Comment: @enrique2334 See update.  You're missing the vx, vy properties from the tutorial's `__init__()`

Comment: Please note the general pattern. Once you understand what "instance" and "attribute" mean, an error message that says "X instance has no attribute 'y'" means exactly what it says, and is perfectly clear.

Answer (score 0):

`dir_x` and `dir_y` are vx and vy you should change them... to vx and vy...